# Дата в Sql запрос

Tags: sql

Всем привет.
Имеется 1 таблица:

### Base

`Name` - Текстовое поле

`Surname` - Текстовое поле

`birthdate` - Дата

На форме имеется `button`, `DateTimePicker` и `TableGrid`.

Дата на `TableGrid` показывается в виде `dd.mm.yyyy`.
На кнопке при нажатии идет следующий SQL запрос:

```
SELECT "$autoinc", Base.Name, Base.Surname, Base.birthdate FROM Base
```

Результат выводится на `TableGrid` в виде `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00`.
Надо чтобы было просто `dd.mm.yyyy`.
Помогите с задачей пожалуйста.

Comment: Уточните реализацию sql: MySql, Oracle, MsSql... Если вы пишете программу, уточните язык программирования.

Answer (score 1):

Варианты решения:

1. Свойство `ToShortDateString()` - строка форматом dd/mm/yyyy
2. Вручную получить из класса поля `$"{mydate.Day}.{mydate.Month}.{mydate.Year}"`

**P.S.** Если поле `birthdate` с типом `datetime`, а не `date` - то по умолчанию будет выводить полную дату со временем.

Answer (score 0):

*В дополнение к ответу @Kryshtop*

Так же можно добавить форматирование в запрос (SQL Server)

```
 SELECT  "$autoinc", 
         Base.Name, 
         Base.Surname, 
         CONVERT(char(10), Base.birthdate, 104) AS birthdate 
 FROM Base
```